# React Toolkit Query updateCachedData, draft type

Tags: typescript, rtk-query

Snippet (`apiSlice.ts`):

```
  async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5994/ws");
    try {
      // Wai for initial query to resolve
      await cacheDataLoaded;

      const listener = (event: MessageEvent) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log("LISTNER", data);

        updateCachedData((draft) => {
          draft.push(data);
        });
      };

      ws.addEventListener("message", listener);
    } catch {
      // No-op for now
    }

    await cacheEntryRemoved;

    ws.close();
  },
```

Typescript is complaining that `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)`. When hovering over `draft` argument, the inferred type is `any`. Looking on GitHub public repos, this seems to work for everyone else..

Why is TypeScript complaining about this, is the type not inferred via RTK Query?

As a result, I get this error when trying to execute `draft.push`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: draft.push is not a function
    at apiSlice.ts:187:21
    at e.produce (immer.esm.mjs:1:16170)
    at e.produceWithPatches (immer.esm.mjs:1:16741)
    at rtk-query.esm.js:489:44
    at index.js:16:1
    at redux-toolkit.esm.js:317:1
    at Object.dispatch (redux.js:691:1)
    at __spreadProps.updateCachedData (rtk-query.esm.js:1451:112)
    at WebSocket.listener (apiSlice.ts:186:13)
```

Comment: Is your endpoint itself typed correctly?